# what is the difference between \twocolumn and \documentclass[twocolumn]{book}

Tags: two-column

what is the difference between `\twocolumn` and `\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}`?
when I use `\twocolumn` , the line spread seems smaller?(compare with the same document using \documentclass[twocolumn]{book}) why?

Comment: I believe that twocolumn option affects your whole document, whereas `\twocolumn` affects only a specific part of your document

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you specify the document class option `twocolumn`, and if use the `book` document class, a default font size of `10pt`, and paper size of A4 or USLetter, the entire document will be typeset in two-column mode, and also:

- `\sloppy` will be in effect,
- the default value of `\parindent` will be `1em`,
- `\textwidth` will be set to either `469pt` (USLetter, ca. 6.49") or `452pt` (A4paper, ca. 6.25").

(The widths of the margins will depend on whether `oneside` or `twoside` is in effect.)

If you do *not* specify this document class option but issue the instruction `\twocolumn`, either in the preamble or somewhere in the body of the document, the subsequent material will be typeset in two-column mode (with a page break inserted first, if necessary), but

- `\sloppy` will not be in effect by default,
- the default value of `\parindent` will be 15pt, and
- `\textwidth` will be set to `345pt` (ca. 4.77").

Oh, and the distance to the margin block is also affected by the presence or absence of the `twocolumn` option.

Of course, default page parameters can be overridden, e.g., via the macros and options of the `geometry` package.

Answer (score 15):

Beside that some format defaults changed (as explained in Mico's answer), it is worth to note that:

- The document class `twocolumn` option can be used only once, but you switch between `\twocolumn` and `\onecolumn` as you want, on a per-page basis (i.e., you cannot switch in the middle of a page, this always cause a page break).
- Nonetheless, you can use `\twocolumn[text in one colum] text in two columns` to switch from one to two columns in the same page, without using the `multicol` package. Note that you cannot include some commands `as \chapter{}` of the standard book class in the optional argument, but it works in `scrbook` or `memoir`class  with the `article` option.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[margin=1in,columnsep=.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,microtype}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[\chapter{Nice chapter with long title and summary}
\hrule\bigskip {\lipsum[1]}\bigskip\hrule\bigskip]
\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

> [image: mwe]

Comment: I used the example without lipsum and adding for instance \textbf or \texttt and does not work. In the first case, text is boldfaced outside the text between braces and in the second case, can't adjust the text to the right margin protuding into the second column.

Comment: @djnavas  I can change `{\lipsum[1]}`by `\textbf{bla bla ... bla}`  or `\texttt{bla bla ... bla}` without any problem. You're making something else wrongly, as using unbreakable long words like `asdfasfdsdfsfasfasdfsfasdf` to test the code.

Comment: my example is too long for a 600 character comment. I leave this link to a code that exemplifies what I try to expose to you: 

http://pastebin.com/Kxn2xMtZ

I gave it one week of retention time.

Comment: I supressed the bold face problem, changing \textbf{... paragraph ... paragraph} with {bfserires ... paragraph ... paragraph ...}, but persists other problems: a) "undefined control sequence" due to \bigskip\hrule\bigskip, even if replace \hrule with \hrulefill; b) several overfull boxes of 5, 18 and 56 pt too wide in paragraph.

Comment: @djnavas 1) You cannot use `\chapter` in a article document class 2) Use `{\bfseries ...}` for several praragrahs in bold, not `\textbf{ ....}`.  3) `\bigskip` and `\hrule` are defined even in the `minimal` document class, so this error should be due to another comands ... Maybe `\chapter`?  4) You have many overfull boxes because words LaTeX does not know  what languages are you using, and therefore words are not hyphenated. Use the `babel` package!. The package `microtype also help a lot when there are a small  text width to avoid a overfull `\hbox`.

Comment: @djnavas  The comments are not the place to solve new problems due to new code not related with the question or the answers.  If you see yourself stuck with error, first search here in TeX.SX for some people asking with similar problems. If you do not find the right question & answer, then open a new question for the problem (only a problem per question, please).